# medianBlur not working in opencv4android

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, opencv3.0, android

I developed an OpenCV application using C++ on my desktop computer, where everything works as expected.

Then I included the C++ code in an android application using android NDK. It builds and runs, however, the result is different than the one on my desktop.

After debugging, I found that the following line makes the difference:

```
cv::medianBlur(img, filteredImage, 9);
```

In fact, medianBlur seems broken on my android device. Consider the following image:

[image: image before medianBlur]

which is transformed to

[image: image after medianBlur]

The device I am using a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 running Android 5.0.
The OpenCV version is 3.0.0.

Do you have any ideas why this happens?

Comment: I have used medianblur & NDK before and everything was fine. are you sure that there is undefined behaviour in your code? for example you are trying to return the Mat by reference from some preprocessing method?

Comment: I do not think this is the problem because if I use e.g. a bilateral filter instead of the medianBlur everything works as expected. Which version of OpenCV and which device did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find out how to solve the problem with opencv4android 3.0.0.

However, after downgrading to version 2.4.11 medianBlur works as expected.

Still, if anyone finds a solution for version 3.0.0 please let me know.